# Why is using register memory slower than shared memory when doing reduction?

Tags: cuda

I evaluated two kernel performances:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void initData_int(int *p, int size){
    for (int t=0; t<size; t++){
        p[t] = (int)(rand()&0xff);
    }
}

__global__ void reduceShfl(int *in, int* out, int size)
{
    extern __shared__ int smem[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x*4;
    smem[tid] = 0;
    if (tid>=size) return;
    int tmp = 0; 
    if (idx + blockDim.x*3 <= size){
        int a = in[idx];
        int b = in[idx+blockDim.x];
        int c = in[idx+2*blockDim.x];
        int d = in[idx+3*blockDim.x];
        tmp = a + b + c + d;
    }
    smem[tid] = tmp;
    __syncthreads();

    if (blockDim.x >= 1024 && tid < 512){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 512];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 512 && tid < 256){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 256];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 256 && tid < 128){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 128];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 128 && tid < 64){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 64];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (blockDim.x >= 64 && tid < 32){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 32];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    
    int tmpsum = smem[tid]; 
    tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 16);
    tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 8);
    tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 4);
    tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 2);
    tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 1);
    if (tid==0)
        out[blockIdx.x] = tmpsum;
}

__global__ void reduceShmUnroll(int *in, int *out, int num)
{
    extern __shared__ int smem[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x*4;
    
    if (tid >= num) return;
    int tmp=0;
    if(idx + blockDim.x*3 <= num)
    {
        int a = in[idx];
        int b = in[idx + blockDim.x];
        int c = in[idx + blockDim.x*2];
        int d = in[idx + blockDim.x*3];
        tmp = a + b + c + d;
    }   
    smem[tid] = tmp;
    __syncthreads();

    if (blockDim.x >= 1024 && tid < 512){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid + 512];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 512 && tid < 256){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid+256];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 256 && tid < 128){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid+128];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (blockDim.x >= 128 && tid < 64){
        smem[tid] += smem[tid+64];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 32){
        volatile int *vsmem = smem;
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+32];
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+16];
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+8];
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+4];
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+2];
        vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+1];
    }

    if (tid == 0) out[blockIdx.x] = smem[0];
}

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    int size = 1<<24;
    int nBytes = size*sizeof(int);
    int *a_h = (int*)malloc(nBytes);
    initData_int(a_h, size);

    int blocksize = 1024;
    int gridsize = (size-1)/blocksize+1;
    dim3 block(blocksize, 1);
    dim3 grid((size-1)/blocksize+1, 1);
    int *a_d, *b_d;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&b_d, grid.x*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int *tmp = (int*)malloc(gridsize*sizeof(int));
    memset(tmp, 0, grid.x/4);
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    auto s_0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    reduceShfl<<<grid, block, blocksize*sizeof(int)>>>(a_d, b_d, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp, b_d, grid.x/4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int res_1 = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<grid.x/4; i++){
        res_1 += tmp[i];
    }
    auto e_0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = e_0 - s_0;
    printf("Result from reduceShfl is: %d and time cost is %2f.\n", res_1, diff.count());

    memset(tmp, 0, grid.x/4);
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    s_0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    reduceShmUnroll<<<grid, block, blocksize*sizeof(int)>>>(a_d, b_d, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp, b_d, grid.x/4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int res_0 = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<grid.x/4; i++){
        res_0 += tmp[i];
    }
    e_0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    diff = e_0 - s_0;
    printf("Result from reduceShmUnroll is: %d and time cost is %2f.\n", res_0, diff.count());

    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(b_d);
    free(a_h);
    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

The main difference is at the last warp reduction, `reduceShmUnroll` is using shared memory and `reduceShfl` is doing warp shuffle, which uses register memory.
But I found that `reduceShfl` is slower than `reduceShmUnroll`.

```
Result from reduceShfl is: 2139353471 and time cost is 0.000533.
Result from reduceShmUnroll is: 2139353471 and time cost is 0.000485.
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: For more exact measurement of kernel execution timing it is better to use [CUDA Events](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/).

In addition, before running kernel timing measurements it is good practice to give the device a little warmup. The first kernel calls executed in fresh context may run slightly slower than they otherwise would. Even then there will be little variance, so you might want to look at best and average timings of 10 or more same kernel calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is sth wrong with my code?

Yes, I would say there is something wrong with your code.

The main problem I see is that you are doing an invalid comparison.  In your shared memory kernel, you are restricting the last warp reduction activity to the last warp.  In the shuffle kernel, you are not:

shared mem kernel:

```
__syncthreads();
if (tid < 32){  // this is missing from your shuffle kernel
    volatile int *vsmem = smem;
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+32];
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+16];
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+8];
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+4];
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+2];
    vsmem[tid] += vsmem[tid+1];
}
```

shuffle kernel:

```
__syncthreads();

int tmpsum = smem[tid]; 
tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 16);
tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 8);
tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 4);
tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 2);
tmpsum += __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, tmpsum, 1);
if (tid==0)
    out[blockIdx.x] = tmpsum;
```

When I restrict your shuffle kernel in the same way that the shared mem kernel is restricted (so that unnecessary warps are not doing unnecessary work) then I observe approximately equal run times (approx 1% difference) between the two kernels when I profile with `nvprof` on V100:

```
                0.38%  222.76us         1  222.76us  222.76us  222.76us  reduceShmUnroll(int*, int*, int)
                0.37%  220.55us         1  220.55us  220.55us  220.55us  reduceShfl(int*, int*, int)
```

That is what I would expect.  For that limited usage, there is no reason to think that either shared mem usage or shuffle will be faster or slower.

Both shared memory activity and warp shuffle activity have throughput limits.  Therefore trying to predict which will be faster is difficult, because it depends on what else is going on in your code.  If your code is bound by shared memory throughput, and you convert some of that activity to warp shuffle, you are likely to see a benefit from warp shuffle. The same statement can be made in the other direction.  For this particular section of this particular code, when written properly/comparably/equivalently, you are not bound *differently* by shared memory throughput nor by warp shuffle throughput, so the correct expectation is no difference in performance, substituting one for the other.

Comment: I add the line you recommended. warp shuffle is faster than the previous one. But still slower than shared memory one. I believe it's determined by both the hardware (2080 ti i'm using) and code activities.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Do you have related material recommended to tell whether an application is  bound by shared memory throughput or warp shuffle throughput?

Comment: Learn to use the profilers.  It's not something that can be covered in comments.  you can get started with the profilers [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-nsight-compute-to-inspect-your-kernels/) and [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/analysis-driven-optimization-preparing-for-analysis-with-nvidia-nsight-compute-part-1/).